# using "set" of two datasets, merges or appends the datasets?

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS and wanted to ask you for the interpretation of the code for the two datasets that I have (sid fullsid):

```
data sid; set sid fullsid; run;
```

Can you please help me to understand what the code of line above does? Does it append the two datasets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is spelled out in the [documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=p00hxg3x8lwivcn1f0e9axziw57y.htm&docsetVersion=3.1&locale=en#p0mq0egdjy8ambn1hxil77ayqkp9).

**Combining SAS Data Sets**

Use a single SET statement with multiple data sets to concatenate the specified data sets. That is, the number of observations in the new data set is the sum of the number of observations in the original data sets, and the order of the observations is all the observations from the first data set followed by all the observations from the second data set, and so on.